# Only scroll UIScrollView, if the label in it is bigger than the View respectively

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have a little problem with the UIScrollView. It scrolls way to far. Is it possible to enable it only, if the label in it is bigger than the ScrollView?

Pictures (sorry, they are quite huge):
[image: without scrolling]

[image: scrolled half way down]

[image: totally down]

[image: Storyboard]

The Label, that is on the ScrollView, is in the ScrollView

Comment: how have you set the height of the contents in the scroll view? this can be done very easily it just depends on how you have setup your view.

Comment: are you using the storyboard to create the view?

Comment: Yes I am. I just did not found how. I set the height according to the top of the tabBar and the bottom of the date

Comment: you need to send me screenshots of how your storyboard is setup. This is a very easy problem to solve but I just need to know how you have setup your scrollview.

Comment: Do you have a label inside of the scrollview? Why don't you just use a textview instead of a scrollview if you only have text in the scrollview?

Comment: I have one inside, but is not the textView writeable? If not, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using a UITextView instead of a scrollview. It looks like you only need text. A textview does NOT have to be editable. You can disable the editable check box in the storyboard. Take a look at my screenshot.

[image: See the highlighted property of textView]

If you do want the scrollview method to work, you will have to add a bottom constraint to the label in your scrollview. It will tell the content view of your scrollview the size of the content within the scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way this could be done is through the Storyboard (auto-layout enabled).

The main idea is to wrap your views (Labels) inside the `UIScrollView` with a `UIView` instead of directly inside the `UIScrollView`, then you need to set the constraints of the `UIView` to match the `UIScrollView` from all sides and add a height and width constraints equaling the `UIScrollView`. The height constraints priority should be lowered (lets say to 750 instead of 1000) so it will allow the scrollView to stretch when needed and the `UILabel`'s button constraint should be set to `greater or equal` to allow the `UILabel` to take it's size and "push" the `UIView` when it needs to.

Last but not least, you need to lower the vertical `content hugging priority`of the `UIScrollView` and the `UIView` to 249 and raise the vertical `content compression resistance` of the `UILabel` to 751.

[Here is a full working example](https://github.com/samermurad/iosAutoResizingScroll)